# Extract and Make TAR archives with Python

Tags: python

Hi I'm working on a package manager in Python and I want the packages to be compressed in TAR format. How can I make and extract TAR archives in Python? I've already read the "tarfile" module documentation and it was rather confusing.

Comment: With the `tarfile` module.

Comment: Docs seems pretty straightforward to me. What problem do you have?

Comment: Plain tar doesn't do compression, it just combines a directory tree into a single file. Perhaps you want a .tar.gz file, in which case you run your tarred data through gzip. BTW, your question in its current form is too broad for SO, and it will probably be put on hold unless / until you focus on a particular issue that is giving you problems. Please see [ask].

Comment: @pacholik The following: I want a bunch of tarfile.whateverthefunctionis commands to find out how to tar my filetree up or extract an existing filetree.tar

Comment: pacholik didn't mean "What problem are you having that you are trying to solve?", they meant "What problem are you having with the `tarfile` documentation?", e.g. do you know how Python works, are you illiterate, etc.

Comment: @user164017:  What is your _specific_ question?  "I want... to `tar` my filetree up" is a goal, not a question.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams:  "illiterate" is a bit much.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase: I'm just trying to cover all the bases.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Ok then, that is my goal, to tar up my filetree but the Python documentation was kind of confusing because it used many words where I wondered wth does this even mean. I've been working with Python for quite some time and I've also written my own modules but as I said the documentation was confusing and I didn't quite understand how to achieve my goal of tarring up my filetree

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams And I would advise you to be precise otherwise with the things you say otherwise there might be a terrible misunderstanding. However, Yes I have worked with Python and no I did not understand the documentation for the simple reason that it used terms unfamiliar to myself. Does that answer your question?

Comment: @user164017:  Again... _specifics_!  The [`tarfile` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html) contain many, many words...  How on Earth are we to guess which ones you didn't understand?  You refuse to tell us!  **No one can answer your question, because you haven't asked it yet.**

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Ok so what is the simplest way to use tarfile.open() to make a trafile? What arguments would I have to put in and how many?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include enough details to make it a complete, answerable question.  your last comment, especially, will never be seen down here in the comments.  Also, if you still want your `.tar` file to be compressed, specify what kind of compression you need.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Normal compression I guess. What kind of details?

Comment: I can't answer that without knowing what you want.  What _kind_ of file do you want when this is over?  The [`tarfile.open` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tarfile.html#tarfile.open) list three options, typically associated with file extensions `.Z`, `.gz`, and `.bz2`.  Which one do you consider "normal"?  Or by "normal" do you mean "not compressed at all"?  All we're asking for here is a single, _specific_ question that another human being could possibly answer without guesswork.  No one enjoys playing "guess the question", and after a dozen+ comments, I'm getting sick of trying.

Comment: Please read "[ask]", and especially the referenced work "[Writing the Perfect Question](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/)".  **Imagine you're someone else trying to answer your question**, and [edit] your question to fill in all the details the someone-else would need to know.   Again, no guesswork allowed.  If you find yourself thinking, "_Obviously_, they would know that I meant...", stop that and fix it.

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase I'm not quite sure what I missed ot on but anyway: I have a folder with two files: plugin.py and MANIFEST.INFO and I wamted to make one file out of these two files. This one file should be called plugin.tar. How do I go about 1) combinig 'plugin.py' and 'MANIFEST.INFO' into 'plugin.tar' with the tarfile module. Note: The file plugin.tar should be in the same directory as the other two files. 2) How do I(being the dev who wants to install the plugin) extract plugin.tar?

Comment: @KevinJ.Chase Clear enough?

Comment: @user164017 *"I have a folder with two files: plugin.py and MANIFEST.INFO and I wamted to make one file out of these two files. (...)"* <-- this is useful context and *actual* questions. You could/should add that to the question itself rather than leaving it here, 10 comments down, where it's hard to find. Your readers will be grateful, future programmers searching for answers will be grateful and you'll get better/more answers.

Comment: @jDo Ok thanks will do so in future!:)

Answer (score 0):

Add files *foo*, *bar* and *quux* to tar archive

```
with tarfile.open("sample.tar", 'w') as tar:
    for name in ["foo", "bar", "quux"]:
        tar.add(name)
```

if you want `tar.gz` use

```
tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", 'w:gz')
```

To extract

```
with tarfile.open("sample.tar.gz", 'r:gz') as tar:
    tar.extractall()
```

Comment: can I just use a variable so like this: 'tar = tarfile.open("sample.tar", "w")' and the the rest? What does line 2 in tge first example do?

Comment: Yes, you can, but don't forget to close it `foo.close()`.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, but what does "for name in [" foo", "bar", " quux"]: do? What is 'name', 'foo', 'bar' and 'quux'? Last pece of info I need:)

Comment: @user164017 Those are names of the files you're about to archive.

Comment: @user164017 Have you really been working with Python for quite some time?

Comment: yes, why? I just don't understand what role name plays.. If you could enlighten me I would be very happy!:)